# uncheckValue not working with (active)checkBoxList

Tags: php, yii, yii-chtml

i have this code to generate an activeCheckBoxList:

```
<?php 
  echo CHtml::activeCheckBoxList($model,
                                 'selected', 
                                 CHtml::listData(AuthItem::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('type'=>2)),
                                                 'name',
                                                 'name'),
                                 array('unCheckValue'=>'Off', 
                                       'labelOptions'=>array('style'=>'display:inline'))
                                 );
 ?>
```

However, the hidden fields are not rendered and when submiting the form, only values for checked fields are send in $_POST['User']['selected'].

I solved it in my own way and will probably switch to dropdown box, changing it to only 1 value, but this is still interesting me. Any ideas?

First try:
Ok, so i tried to change it to

```
'uncheckValue'=>'Off'
```

It is true that with it named unCheckValue it was generated as attribute of the checkbox, now it isnt, but there is still not a hidden field for each checkbox.

However a hidden field IS generated, but only one for the whole CheckBoxList...
I expected it to generate a hidden field for EACH checkbox, sothat when submiting and having an unselected checkbox with ie. ID = 'Option_1', in the $_POST i would find 'Option_1'=>'Off' ?

So that i could do a foreach and do: (pseudocode)

```
foreach(Checkbox)
    if(Value = 'Off') deactivate();
    else activate()
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `unCheckValue` to `uncheckValue`

Because of the typo `unCheckValue` becomes an attribute of the checkbox.

```
<?php 
    echo CHtml::activeCheckBoxList($model,
                             'selected', 
                             CHtml::listData(AuthItem::model()->findAllByAttributes(array('type'=>2)),
                                             'name',
                                             'name'),
                             array('uncheckValue'=>'Off', 
                                   'labelOptions'=>array('style'=>'display:inline'))
                             );
?>
```

Comment: hm, i am pretty 95% sure i tried uncheckValue too, will try again in about 2 hours and report.... if it will be this i will face palm so hard...